# How to implement the website theme to my template in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am fairly new to odoo, and for my internship i need to create a module with a website.
For the website I am already able to display a small bit of text on an empty white page.

here is my current working code:

The Template:

```
<template id="moestuin_webpage">
    <div>
      <h1>Testje</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

The Controller:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import http

class Moestuin(http.Controller):

@http.route('/moestuin/', auth='public')
def index(self, **kw):
    #return "Hello, world"
    return http.request.render('moestuin.moestuin_webpage')
```

As stated above, this results a white page displaying "Testje"

But whenever I try to add the website.layout (as seen from other modules) to my Template like this:

```
<template id="moestuin_webpage">
  <t t-call="website.layout">
    <div>
      <h1>Testje</h1>
    </div>
  </t>
</template>
```

I only get an error on my page

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

I searched everywhere for solutions, but I couldn't find anything.

Any ideas on how to get this to work, am I forgetting anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fulfill all the steps from here: [odoo website support](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html#website-support)

- have the dependency correctly configured
- use `auth='public'` and `website=True` in your route
- now you can use `t-call='website.layout`